# how to get length of substring in Regular Expression JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

here is my regular expression

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{40}([a-zA-Z0-9-]{3}2[a-zA-Z0-9-]{12}){2,10}$/
```

There will be one condition: the length of every string after first 40 characters must be 16 characters. This 16 characters string will be non repeating and minimum of 2 times and maximum of 10 times. So i want to get the length of this sub-string which should be 16.

Here is input string:

```
string input="PR212D4EB2-6B25-4020-BD2A-941F69C0AA4102GEX2421262506027GEX2437345435522"
```

I want to match the length of "GEX2421262506027" and "GEX2437345435522". Like this, there will be 10 strings max. I want to validate if this length should be 16 characters.

Comment: do you have an example the string this regex is inteded to match?

Comment: a. your entire last sentence is not comprehensive, can you please elaborate?

Comment: he is trying to ask have you got any string value on which you have tried this regular expression

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/jO8rS5

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{40}([a-zA-Z0-9-]{3}2[a-zA-Z0-9-]{12}){2,10}$/;            
  var exp = text.match(pattern);
  if (exp) {
   alert(exp[0].length);
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I have an input string. I want to match that string's last 16 characters.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want the last 16 characters:

```
var string = 'PR212D4EB2-6B25-4020-BD2A-941F69C0AA4102GEX2421262506027GEX2437345435522';
var matching = string.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{40}([a-zA-Z0-9-]{3}2[a-zA-Z0-9-]{12}){2,10}$/);
console.log(matching[1]);
console.log(matching[1].length);
```